# How to remove Background color in the Angular 2 templates in Webstorm

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have this 'green' background in the template and style in the Angular 2 in WebStorm. How can I remove this color ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Untick the **Background** option for the **Injected language fragment** here:

[image: injected]